# Как сократить и оптимизировать код js

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="stars">
<a href="#"><img src="images/star_empty_grey.svg"  class="star1" onclick="activeStar1(1)"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/star_empty_grey.svg"  class="star1" onclick="activeStar1(2)"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/star_empty_grey.svg"  class="star1" onclick="activeStar1(3)"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/star_empty_grey.svg"  class="star1" onclick="activeStar1(4)"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/star_empty_grey.svg"  class="star1" onclick="activeStar1(5)"></a>
</div>
```

есть такой блок с кодом JS:

```
var stars1 = doc.getElementsByClassName('star1'),
appraisal3 = false;
function activeStar1(n){
    if(appraisal3 == false && i < n){
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        stars1[i].src = '../images/star_active_gold.svg';
    }
    appraisal3 = true;
    }else{
        stars1[0].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
        stars1[1].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
        stars1[2].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
        stars1[3].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
        stars1[4].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
    appraisal3 = false;
    i = 0;
    }
};
```

Как можно записать в сокращенном варианте если таких блоков 19? Просто не хочется грузить сайт лишним скриптом

Comment: почему в первом случае используется цикл, а во втором - нет?

Comment: выдает ошибку связаную с src: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined. Потому решил выйти из положения по-тупому

Comment: потому что `n` у тебя никак не зависит от количества элементов в коллекции `stars1`. Если `n` будет больше чем количество элементов, то ты как раз и получишь указанное исключение

Comment: for (i = 4; i > n; i--) {
  stars000[i].src = "../images/star_empty_grey.svg";
 }
 appraisal = false;
 i = 0;

Comment: Вот в чем прикол что элементы меняются только через 1 тоесть если нажимаешь на 3 элемент то меняется 5, а должен менятся 5 и 4

Comment: а зачем тебе обратный порядок, если твой цикл отлично работает в обоих случаях? у тебя только значение для src меняется - все остальное точно такое же

Comment: ну так у тебя `n` на единицу больше чем индекс в массиве. Индексы ведут отсчет с 0, а не единицы

Comment: Эти 5 элементов это звезды при клике они окрашиваются слева на право в желтый цвет если я нажимаю  на 2 звезду, звезды должны справа налево окрасится в серый цвет

Comment: _ну так у тебя `n` на единицу больше чем индекс в массиве. Индексы ведут отсчет с 0, а не единицы_

Comment: я так понимаю мне надо сместить все цифры элемента n на единицу

Comment: скорее просто сделать `-1` в цикле, `for (i = 4; i > n-1; i--)` а то и `-2`, так как строгое неравенство

Comment: Спасибо большое очень помог ты мне)